# Can’t make Pagination search with keyword running

Tags: php, codeigniter

Does anyone know how to make the pagination search with keyword running on second page link using CodeIgniter?

I would like to add a pagination to my search. My keyword search seems to work fine, I’m using one search key form, I can see first page display correctly but the problem is I can’t make second page link working and others pages links. Assuming there are two different Requests made (when user click on search button, pagination links)

How can I make pagination link running?

Answer (score 1):

Have you successfully created paginated links yet?

You need to have a CI function called e.g. "search". This will take two parameters, search_query and page.

For every page load you need to re-run the search query but using the LIMIT function in SQL to only get back the required results i.e. for that page range.. You also need to set the number of results per page somewhere too.

I don't have my CI projects with me now to post code but you should be thinking along these lines:

SELECT required_info
FROM searchable_table
WHERE searchable_field = "search query"
LIMIT 0, 49

The above query will return results for the first page containing 50 results.

To do this for the second page you use: LIMIT 50, 100 and so on...

to calculate the first parameter use: resultsPerPage * pageNum

Comment: @Connor H: Yes I did successfully created paginated links. I was trying to use set a session and added it to base_url string but when I clicked on second page and next pages. It displays the item NOT from keyword search.

Comment: At first sessions are the easiest solution to passing data around but a bad idea. What if the user is browsing search results for two different queries out of the same session.. One will get overwritten.

I think you will need to post some code if you need further help.

Comment: But I only have one single search input